# SQL query make an union and an order by random in only the second section

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm making a SQL query to get the billboard on my site. I need a specific billboard to arrive first and the other to be order randomly. So I need the first part to always arrive first and after the union I need it to be order randomly, right now everything is being order randomly. How can I fixe my query ?

```
    $query = "SELECT idadvertisement as id, alt_fr as alt, src_fr as src, url_fr as url, video_fr as video, nofollow as nofollow FROM advertisement WHERE type = 'billboard' AND active = 1 AND idadvertisement=61 AND src_fr IS NOT NULL AND src_fr <> '' AND (NOW() BETWEEN date_start AND date_end) 
              UNION
             SELECT idadvertisement as id, alt_fr as alt, src_fr as src, url_fr as url, video_fr as video, nofollow as nofollow FROM advertisement WHERE type = 'billboard' AND active = 1 AND idadvertisement <> 9 AND src_fr IS NOT NULL AND src_fr <> '' AND (NOW() BETWEEN date_start AND date_end) ORDER BY RAND()"
```

Thanks !

Comment: What DBMS are you using, MySQL or SQL Server? Please remove inappropriate tags.

Comment: I'm using MySQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a `union` at all.  Just order by what you want to order by:

```
SELECT idadvertisement as id, alt_fr as alt, src_fr as src, url_fr as url,
       video_fr as video, nofollow as nofollow
FROM advertisement
WHERE type = 'billboard' AND
      active = 1 AND
      idadvertisement <> 9 AND
      src_fr IS NOT NULL AND
      src_fr <> '' AND 
      NOW() BETWEEN date_start AND date_end
order by (idadvertisement = 61) desc,
         rand()
```

You seem to what `idadvertisement` 61 to go first.  That is what the first key does.  The rest are just randomized.